# Creating an executable .jar file

Tags: java, executable-jar

I use JCreator. After checking the internet and other posts on this website, I created a jar file using JCreator and opened it using WinRAR. After entering the MANIFEST.MF, I typed "Main-Class: " and specified which class my main method was in. Next, I saved it and attempted to run the .jar file, but to no avail. Absolutely NOTHING happened. Can someone explain to me what occurred and how I should create the jar file? The file should open the command prompt of the computer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file This answer contains info on how to create executable jar files that can be run using a double-click.

This should help.

Comment: @user3046986 What does that have to do with this question?  He is not talking about an exe.  Just a jar with a main - class

Comment: I personally suggest Eclipse. It would be very simple for you to just export your project as a runnable JAR.

Comment: when you opened jar file via WinRar it unpacked jar to the temp folder. So you have edited and saved manifest in a temp folder, not in the jar file. Unpack jar file contents to the folder you have created, then modify manifest and compose jar file via `jar` utility which can be found in `your_java_sdk/bin` folder.

Comment: did you add all resources and directorys (eg. if u read a file out of it)

Comment: To debug and get more information about why your JAR won't start, you can run `java -jar nameOfJarFile.jar` from command-line. That will tell you what goes wrong when it fails to start.

Comment: i tried what @Chronio said, it worked! Now I'm very confused. Isn't the jar file supposed to run upon double click????? or is it because there's a file in a file(directory in a directory)???